# Why its displaying with only one space in between

Tags: jquery

I am having this in my HTML

```
<div class="t1t2Wrapper" style="padding:0px 10px 0px">
   <ul class="breadcrumb pull-left" id="mybreadcumb" brand_name_attr="General" document_id="204" style="background:none; margin-bottom:0px;">
      <li>Name<i class="icon-angle-right"></i></li>
      <li>Text1  Text2<i></i></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

(There are two spaces between Text1 and Text2)

I am creating this t1t2wrapper dynamically

```
 $('.t1t2Wrapper').append(htmlforTree);
                    requested_data = [];
                 $('#mybreadcumb').children('li').each(function () {
                     requested_data.push($(this).text().trim());

                      })
```

But while displaying its only displaying with one space only  ??

Ths is my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/02jm17kf/

Comment: Because that's how HTML works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have more than one space in HTML, you need to use `&nbsp;` - [the non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

See here:

```html
<li>Text1  Text2<i></i></li>
<li>Text1&nbsp;&nbsp;Text2<i></i></li>
```

Note: [the `pre` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) would also work, but I don't think you want to use it in your example.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to use &nbsp; in my case ??

Comment: Absolutely, just gave you an example.

Comment: Thank you , but the problem is that i am creating this dynamically as shown (updated my question )

Comment: I see, you can use simple string replace method if you're not able to modify the original content. `.replace(' ', '&nbsp;')`

Answer (score 0):

In HTML are more whitespaces shown as a space (one space).

As a whitespace in this case I mean spaces, tabs, new lines, etc.

Answer (score 0):

HTML does not allow two spaces. However You could use `&nbsp;` or [other space](http://zoerooney.com/blog/web-development/the-details-breaks-spaces-and-non-breaking-spaces/) that fits your needs.

```
<li>Text1 &nbsp;Text2<i></i></li>
```